# WP_Query + Nested Arguments + Like - adds junk characters when printed query

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to fetch results from DB using WP_Query();

```
$creditCardTotalQuery = new WP_Query($args);
```

My $args looks as below.

```
Array
(
[numberposts] => -1
[post_type] => credit_card
[meta_query] => Array
    (
        [relation] => AND
        [0] => Array
            (
                [relation] => OR
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => i_want
                        [value] => Rewards
                        [compare] => LIKE
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => i_want
                        [value] => Cashback
                        [compare] => LIKE
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

When I printed a query using **$creditCardTotalQuery->request**, it generates query like

```
SELECT 
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  pap_posts.ID 
FROM 
    pap_posts  INNER JOIN pap_postmeta 
    ON ( pap_posts.ID = pap_postmeta.post_id ) 
WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  ( 
    ( pap_postmeta.meta_key = 'i_want' AND pap_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '{1b14e1889648f80eafd2fc4b4c94b5d5e55c3f93f02bc86eff070dc690ecb630}Rewards{1b14e1889648f80eafd2fc4b4c94b5d5e55c3f93f02bc86eff070dc690ecb630}' ) 
    OR 
    ( pap_postmeta.meta_key = 'i_want' AND pap_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '{1b14e1889648f80eafd2fc4b4c94b5d5e55c3f93f02bc86eff070dc690ecb630}Cashback{1b14e1889648f80eafd2fc4b4c94b5d5e55c3f93f02bc86eff070dc690ecb630}' )
  )
) 
    AND pap_posts.post_type = 'credit_card' 
    AND (
        pap_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR 
        pap_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR 
        pap_posts.post_status = 'future' OR 
        pap_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR 
        pap_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR 
        pap_posts.post_status = 'private'
    ) 
GROUP BY 
    pap_posts.ID 
ORDER BY 
    pap_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

I am not sure why it is adding **{1b14e1889648f80eafd2fc4b4c94b5d5e55c3f93f02bc86eff070dc690ecb630}** into the query.

I am using **WordPress 5.3.3**, can someone acknowledge me of this strange behavior?

Comment: Perhaps it substitues Rewards and Cashback with these values

Comment: Do you know how to stop this unpredicted behavior?

Comment: `unset($args['meta_query']); $creditCardTotalQuery = new WP_Query($args);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using like statement with $wpdb->prepare showing hashes where wildcard characters are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53831586/using-like-statement-with-wpdb-prepare-showing-hashes-where-wildcard-character)